# Bind ObjectContext using Ninject in InSingletonScope or not

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, ninject.web.mvc

I have repository with constructor which looks like

```
public Repository(ObjectContext context)
{
    _context = context;
    _objectSet = _context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
}
```

I use Ninject in my MVC app to bind ObjectContext like this

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Entities"].ConnectionString;    
kernel.Bind(typeof(ObjectContext)).ToMethod(context => new Entities(connectionString)).InSingletonScope();
```

I am not sure about `InSingletonScope` in this case. Should I use it or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost certainly not, you want to make sure that each repository is separate and for example a call to savechanges on one will not commit things from another repository.

I would also recommend using DbContext instead of ObjectContext.

Comment: Could you please explain the last suggestion? Why DbContext instead of ObjectContext?

Comment: DbContext is the new context wrapper since EF 4.1 It tidies and simplifies access see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/06/21/productivity-improvements-for-the-entity-framework.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/06/ef-feature-ctp5-model-amp-database-first-with-dbcontext.aspx